# How to import ReactJS es6 code into Express app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, ecmascript-6

I want to render my ReactJS app initially on server using ExpressJS.

Even though I managed to import ES6 modules using *require()*, when module is loaded it crashes because that module contains ES6 code(ES6 import and export).

**Index Route**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var React = require('react');
var ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');

var App = require('../../src/app').default(); 
var template = require('../../src/template').default();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    const appString = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(App)
    res.send(template({
        body: appString,
        title: 'Some title'
    }));
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Template component which returns my initial html:**

```
export default ({ body, title }) => {
  return `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>${title}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/index.css" />
      </head>

      <body>
        <div id="root">${body}</div>
      </body>

      <script src="/assets/bundle.js"></script>
    </html>
  `;
};
```

**App.js - Component I want to turn into string**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

*npm start*

```
C:\Users\zivan\Desktop\weep\client\src\app.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import React, { Component } from 'react';
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\zivan\Desktop\weep\client\server\routes\index.js:7:43)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! server@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the server@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the server package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs server
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls server
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\zivan\Desktop\weep\client\server\npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`babel-node`](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#babel-node) to compile ES6 code before running it.

But it is not meant for production use. You should not be using `babel-node` in production. It is unnecessarily heavy, with high memory usage due to the cache being stored in memory. You will also always experience a startup performance penalty as the entire app needs to be compiled on the fly.

Check out the [example Node.js server with Babel](https://github.com/babel/example-node-server) for an idea of how to use Babel in a production deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Node does not support ES2015 import statements.  Use `require`.

This article can provide a full in-depth example of what you are trying to do:

https://blog.yld.io/2015/06/10/getting-started-with-react-and-node-js/#.WLJAsRIrJP0